# Two-way binding does not work for header fields

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am using `OData V2 Model` and I have set default binding Mode to `TwoWay`, but fields on header level do not get changed in the model, and when I try to submit, `model` has no changes and do not submit. But if I change some field in a `table` (`aggregation`), `model` get changes and submit works.

Any idea why `TwoWay` binding mode works in only `aggregations`?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Could you add the code to show how you are binding the header level fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two way will work if we set the binding syntas as complex in the bootstrap script tag in index.html file as mentioned below:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
.
.
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
.
.
></script>
```